# Sum tables within tbody for multiple tables separately

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have multiple tables where I want to sum all td under tbody and output the value in the thead. I also have multiple tables as I'm using the sortable jquery function to move td rows between the tables and it would be great if the sum number updates on drag and drop.

The values are in string format but I could probably create a data-object with the value if that makes it easier. I'm using jquery but plain javascript works too.

The table should look like the following (The bold numbers are the ones that should be calculated):

```html
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <td>Main object A</td>
          <td><b>120000</b></td>
          <td><b>45000</b></td>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Object A</td>
          <td>100 000</td>
          <td>20 000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Object B</td>
          <td>10 000</td>
          <td>25 000</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <td>Main object B</td>
          <td><b>220000</b></td>
          <td><b>35000</b></td>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Object A</td>
          <td>200 000</td>
          <td>20 000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Object B</td>
          <td>10 000</td>
          <td>25 000</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: Ok, what have you tried so far? Show us that and detail any problems you're having and we'll help if we can.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to calculate sum of value in one column of all rows table table finding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37276167/how-to-calculate-sum-of-value-in-one-column-of-all-rows-table-table-finding)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i didnt completely understand what you need but it should be something like this.
if you light me up i can help you get what you want

```js
$("table").each(function(index, el) {
  var sum = 0;
  $(el).find("tbody > tr > td:nth-child(2)").each(function(i, e) {
    sum += parseInt($(e).html().replace(" ", ""));
  });
  $(el).find("thead > tr > td").eq(1).html(sum);

  var sum1 = 0;
  $(el).find("tbody > tr > td:nth-child(3)").each(function(i, e) {
    sum1 += parseInt($(e).html().replace(" ", ""));
  });
  $(el).find("thead > tr > td").eq(2).html(sum1);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>Main object A</td>
      <td>[Sum of below tbody fields A]</td>
      <td>[Sum of below tbody fields B]</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Object A</td>
      <td>100 000</td>
      <td>20 000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Object B</td>
      <td>10 000</td>
      <td>25 000</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>Main object B</td>
      <td>[Sum of below tbody fields A]</td>
      <td>[Sum of below tbody fields B]</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Object A</td>
      <td>100 000</td>
      <td>20 000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Object B</td>
      <td>10 000</td>
      <td>25 000</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I updated my question to clarify, it should not be the table rows horizontally but vertically that is being calculated. My fault for misinforming.

Comment: Hm.. I didn't down vote. The solutions is perfect and exactly what I was looking for! Thank you!

Comment: tanks buddy i hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this. Basically, the code finds the elements you want to sum and then appends it to the Object total area. The code adds up the numbers Objects row, and then puts the total of `A` on the top left, and the total for `B` on the top right:

```js
let tables = $("table").toArray(); // Get all the tables
let a = false;
for(table of tables) { // Loop through each table
  let tableRow = $(table).find('tbody').find('tr').toArray(); // Get the tr data for each object
  let total = 0;
  for(tableData of tableRow) {
    for(data of $(tableData).children().toArray()) {
      let number = $(data).html().replace(' ', '');
      if(!isNaN(number)) { // If the string is considered a number then add it
       total += parseInt(number);
      }
    }
    let totalElements = $(table).find('thead').find('td').toArray();
    $(totalElements[a + 1]).html(total);
    a = !a;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>Main object A</td>
      <td>[Sum of below tbody fields A]</td>
      <td>[Sum of below tbody fields B]</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Object A</td>
      <td>100 000</td>
      <td>20 000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Object B</td>
      <td>10 000</td>
      <td>25 000</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>Main object B</td>
      <td>[Sum of below tbody fields A]</td>
      <td>[Sum of below tbody fields B]</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Object A</td>
      <td>100 000</td>
      <td>20 000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Object B</td>
      <td>10 000</td>
      <td>25 000</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```