# how to get the sum of all row value in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to achieve two additions in my code.

1. I am trying to get the sum of the row values in the last column of the row
2. I am trying to get the sum of all the final columns in another div

I've achieved the first, my code gives me the correct value of each row. However the second sum is not populating the addition. It's giving me the same value of each row, but I want the value of all rows.

```js
$('.bonus-sum').keyup(function() {
  var sum = 0;
  var salary = parseFloat($(this).closest('tr').find('.wagein').text());
  var bonus = parseFloat($(this).closest('tr').find('.bonus-sum').val()) || 0;
  $(this).closest('tr').find('.bonus-in:checked').each(function() {
    sum = salary + bonus;
  });
  $(this).closest('tr').find('.netpay').text(sum.toFixed(2));
  var netpay = 0;
  netpay += sum;
  $('#total').text('₹ ' + netpay.toFixed(2));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class="text-center"><input type="checkbox" checked="checked" class="checkAll" name="checkAll" /></th>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>Beneficiary Name</th>
        <th class="text-right box">Bonus ₹</th>
        <th class="text-right">Salary ₹</th>
        <th class="text-right">Net pay ₹</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="checkbox" id="bene_id" checked="checked" class="bonus-in" name="bene_id[]" value="" />
        </td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Chellammal Kochimoni</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="bonus_temp" class="bonus-sum" name="bonus_temp[]" value="" /></td>
        <td class="wagein">400</td>
        <td class="netpay"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="checkbox" id="bene_id" checked="checked" class="bonus-in" name="bene_id[]" value="" />
        </td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>Christal Prema G.</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="bonus_temp" class="bonus-sum" name="bonus_temp[]" value="" /></td>
        <td class="wagein">400</td>
        <td class="netpay"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="checkbox" id="bene_id" checked="checked" class="bonus-in" name="bene_id[]" value="" />
        </td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>Kamalesan T.</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="bonus_temp" class="bonus-sum" name="bonus_temp[]" value="" /></td>
        <td class="wagein">400</td>
        <td class="netpay"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="checkbox" id="bene_id" checked="checked" class="bonus-in" name="bene_id[]" value="" />
        </td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>Palammal A.</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="bonus_temp" class="bonus-sum" name="bonus_temp[]" value="" /></td>
        <td class="wagein">400</td>
        <td class="netpay"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="checkbox" id="bene_id" checked="checked" class="bonus-in" name="bene_id[]" value="" />
        </td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>Thangapazham</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="bonus_temp" class="bonus-sum" name="bonus_temp[]" value="" /></td>
        <td class="wagein">400</td>
        <td class="netpay"></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<div>Total Net Pay <span id="total">₹ 0.00</span></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for Editing the question bro.

Comment: _“but I want the value of all rows”_ - well then you need to actually loop over all rows, which you are not currently doing. Plus, IDs _must_ be unique withing an HTML document, so that is the first thing you should fix.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to calculate sum of value in one column of all rows table table finding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37276167/how-to-calculate-sum-of-value-in-one-column-of-all-rows-table-table-finding)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix this you need to create a loop which iterates through *all* the `.netpay` elements, not just the one which was updated, and generates the total value.

In addition, you need to perform the same action when the checkbox is changed. The logic itself can also be made more succinct and DRY, like this:

```js
$('.bonus-sum').on('input', updateRowTotal);
$('.bonus-in').on('change', updateRowTotal).trigger('change'); // trigger is to set values on load

function updateRowTotal() {
  let $tr = $(this).closest('tr');
  let salary = parseFloat($tr.find('.wagein').text()) || 0;
  let bonus = parseFloat($tr.find('.bonus-sum').val()) || 0
  let rowTotal = salary + ($tr.find('.bonus-in:checked').length ? bonus : 0);
  $tr.find('.netpay').text(rowTotal.toFixed(2));

  updateTotal();
}

function updateTotal() {
  let total = 0;
  $('.netpay').each((i, el) => total += parseFloat(el.textContent.trim() || 0));
  $('#total').text('₹ ' + total.toFixed(2));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class="text-center"><input type="checkbox" checked="checked" class="checkAll" name="checkAll" /></th>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>Beneficiary Name</th>
        <th class="text-right box">Bonus ₹</th>
        <th class="text-right">Salary ₹</th>
        <th class="text-right">Net pay ₹</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" class="bonus-in" name="bene_id[]" value="" />
        </td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Chellammal Kochimoni</td>
        <td><input type="text" class="bonus-sum" name="bonus_temp[]" value="" /></td>
        <td class="wagein">400</td>
        <td class="netpay"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" class="bonus-in" name="bene_id[]" value="" />
        </td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>Christal Prema G.</td>
        <td><input type="text" class="bonus-sum" name="bonus_temp[]" value="" /></td>
        <td class="wagein">400</td>
        <td class="netpay"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" class="bonus-in" name="bene_id[]" value="" />
        </td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>Kamalesan T.</td>
        <td><input type="text" class="bonus-sum" name="bonus_temp[]" value="" /></td>
        <td class="wagein">400</td>
        <td class="netpay"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" class="bonus-in" name="bene_id[]" value="" />
        </td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>Palammal A.</td>
        <td><input type="text" class="bonus-sum" name="bonus_temp[]" value="" /></td>
        <td class="wagein">400</td>
        <td class="netpay"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" class="bonus-in" name="bene_id[]" value="" />
        </td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>Thangapazham</td>
        <td><input type="text" class="bonus-sum" name="bonus_temp[]" value="" /></td>
        <td class="wagein">400</td>
        <td class="netpay"></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<div>Total Net Pay <span id="total">₹ 0.00</span></div>
```

Note the removal of all the duplicate `id` attributes in your HTML . They are invalid, and are not required anyway.

Comment: i forget to ask one more function in above jquery. can you able to write the code for the master check box in the table header?

Answer (score 0):

I have introduced new variable totalsum.
Replace the below function .your code will work as expected

```
 <script>
       var totalsum=0;
        $('.bonus-sum').keyup(function() {
       var sum = 0;

      var salary = parseFloat($(this).closest('tr').find('.wagein').text());
      var bonus = parseFloat($(this).closest('tr').find('.bonus-sum').val()) || 0;
      $(this).closest('tr').find('.bonus-in:checked').each(function() {
        sum = salary + bonus;
        totalsum+=sum;
      });

     $(this).closest('tr').find('.netpay').text(sum.toFixed(2));
      var netpay = 0;
      netpay += totalsum;
      $('#total').text('₹ ' + netpay.toFixed(2));



    });

 </script>
```